# Does it make sense to colonize planets in enemy territory?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

I started my first game in a small map and ended up with five enemies completely surrounding my territory from the start. I found habitable planets within their influence area and thought the borders would change if I colonize them. Apparently I was wrong. (The planet does not border my influence area directly, and it did not generate influence area by itself.)

The planet now belongs to me, but is within enemy borders. As far as I read this will likely lead to a rebellion soon.

Is it always a bad idea to colonize planets in enemy territory? What tactics can I use to colonize more planets if almost all of them are within enemy influence area?

Comment: (No full answerbecause can't check from here, at work) Your planet *is* generating influence, but not very much of it because it's brand new and underpopulated, and until it has generated more *total* influence in the area than the enemy has in that particular area, it'll stay  within enemy borders.

Comment: That said, since influence drops off with range once your planet starts generating influence from population and improvements (and you may want to help this along with some troop transports and some extra influence buildings) it will overpower the enemy's longer-distance influence in relatively short order -- assuming that the enemy hasn't been in control of that area for terribly long.

Comment: @Shadur Thanks for your comments. Any chance you could flesh this out a bit to a full answer? I find the whole influence and territory topic very confusing, and couldn't find a good explanation anywhere yet. Even the [GalCiv Wiki](http://galciv.wikia.com/wiki/Influence) is really short on the topic and leaves out many aspects.